# Unix Programming Change Directory

Tags: unix

Please can someone explain to me these:

```
$ cd /usr/local/bin
```

changes to directory `/usr/local/bin`.

then to change to the directory `/usr/home/amrood`  from the present directory, use, the relative path:

```
$ cd ../../home/amrood
```

(it is the double dots in the relative path, I don't understand)

cheers

Comment: I don't think changing directory to `../../home/amrood` when current working directory is `/usr/local/bin`, will work. One `..` would change to `/usr/local` and another `..` will change to `/usr`, and there is no `home` in `/usr`, not normally.

Answer (score 1):

Double dots in a unix filepath mean "go up one directory". So if you are in `/usr/local/bin` the `../..` means you basically remove the `bin` and `local` from your current path. (You move "up" two directorys.) Then `home` and `amrood` is added so you end up in `/usr/home/amrood`.

Answer (score 1):

You're traversing back one node of the tree with each `..`. First `/usr/local`, then to `/usr`). So you're at the `usr` directory which means you can navigate to `home/amrood`. To shorten this up, you can do `../../home/amrood`.

Answer (score 1):

From `/usr/local/bin`, you could use absolute path :

```
$ cd /usr/home/amrood
```

Or relative path :

```
$ cd ../../home/amrood
```

But there is no `/usr/home/user`. To get into the current user directory, you should use the shortcut `~` :

```
$ cd ~
$ pwd    # /home/user
```

---

The double dot means "go up to parent directory".

So, for example, from user home starting point :

```
$ pwd     # /home/user
$ cd ..
$ pwd     # /home
```